# Deploying NestJS project using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, nestjs, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have a simple NestJS + Apollo Server + GraphQL project.

You can find the project here: https://github.com/GabeShin/nestjs-graphql-sample

Here's the issue:

- I want to deploy my sample project using AWS CDK, but queries at AppSync is not working properly.
- I searched web for similar implementation, but I'm having difficult time finding a project that is using NestJS framework with AppSync.
- When I send a GraphQL query from deployed AppSync API, I'm getting Error Type  `UnableToAssumeRoleValidationError`

I think my lack of knowledge of AWS infrastructure is causing issue and I need some help.

Here's the CDK code:

```js
        const dependenciesLayer = new LayerVersion(this, 'DependenciesLayer', {
            code: new AssetCode('modules/nestjs-graphql-template/node_modules'),
            compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.NODEJS_14_X, Runtime.NODEJS_16_X],
        });

        const testLambda = new Function(this, 'TestHandler', {
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
            code: new AssetCode('modules/nestjs-graphql-template/dist'),
            handler: 'index.handler',
            layers: [dependenciesLayer],
        });

        const api = new CfnGraphQLApi(this, 'TestApi', {
            name: 'TestApi',
            authenticationType: 'API_KEY',
        });

        const schemafile = fs.readFileSync(
            'modules/nestjs-graphql-template/schema.graphql'
        );

        const schema = new CfnGraphQLSchema(this, 'MyGraphqlSchema', {
            apiId: api.attrApiId,
            definition: schemafile.toString(),
        });

        const dataSource = new CfnDataSource(this, 'TestDataSource', {
            apiId: api.attrApiId,
            name: 'TestDataSource',
            type: 'AWS_LAMBDA',
            lambdaConfig: {
                lambdaFunctionArn: testLambda.functionArn,
            },
        });
```

#### index.ts

```js
import { Server } from 'http';
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { createServer, proxy, Response } from 'aws-serverless-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { createApp } from 'src/main';

let cachedServer: Server;

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Server> {
  const expressApp = express();

  const app = await createApp(expressApp);
  await app.init();

  return createServer(expressApp);
}

export async function handler(event: any, context: Context): Promise<Response> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const server = await bootstrap();
    cachedServer = server;
  }

  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per [their example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/appsync-graphql-dynamodb/index.ts) and the code documentation (node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-appsync/lib/appsync.generated.d.ts):

```
/**
 * The AWS Identity and Access Management service role ARN for the data source. The system assumes this role when accessing the data source.
 *
 * Required if `Type` is specified as `AWS_LAMBDA` , `AMAZON_DYNAMODB` , `AMAZON_ELASTICSEARCH` , or `AMAZON_OPENSEARCH_SERVICE` .
 *
 * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appsync-datasource.html#cfn-appsync-datasource-servicerolearn
 */
readonly serviceRoleArn?: string;
```

you need to add a serviceRoleArn to your dataSource.
For instance:

```js
const lambdaRole = new Role(this, 'LambdaRole', {
    assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('appsync.amazonaws.com'),
});
lambdaRole.addManagedPolicy(
    ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSLambda_FullAccess'),
);
const dataSource = new CfnDataSource(this, 'TestDataSource', {
    apiId: api.attrApiId,
    name: 'TestDataSource',
    type: 'AWS_LAMBDA',
    lambdaConfig: {
        lambdaFunctionArn: testLambda.functionArn,
    },
    serviceRoleArn: lambdaRole.roleArn
});
```